# Visual Studio 2017 default startup project saved to file

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have a vs2017 project, SLN file only, no SUO file.  When I open the solution and go to properties its set to Currently Selected for startup project.  Unless I set that manually to one of my projects, the other data migration project doesnt get the connection string when I do Update-Database.  I tried re-ordering the projects in the SLN file but that didn't affect it.  After changing the default project in settings though it doesnt actually update any of the source controlled files, and I dont see a SUO file.  Any advice on how to modify the files of a solution to set the default startup project to a single specific project?

Answer (score 4):

Startup project is deliberately saved to the .suo file, which is the user-specific settings for the solution.  The .suo file has moved to `.vs\SolutionName\v15\.suo` instead of being right next to the .sln file.

This is to avoid cases such as where Bill, the hypothetical backend developer who only cares about an API project, and Fred, the front-end engineer who only cares about the website project, don't end up conflicting with each other's settings.

That said, the `Update-Database` cmdlet should take any necessary parameters to accomplish the task.  In this case, it's the `-StartupProjectName` parameter.  Note that other cmdlets may use a different parameter name.

```
PM> get-help update-database

NAME
    Update-Database

SYNOPSIS
    Applies any pending migrations to the database.


SYNTAX
    Update-Database [-SourceMigration <String>] [-TargetMigration <String>] [-Script] [-Force] [-ProjectName <String>] [-StartUpProjectName <String>] 
    [-ConfigurationTypeName <String>] [-ConnectionStringName <String>] [-AppDomainBaseDirectory <String>] [<CommonParameters>]

    Update-Database [-SourceMigration <String>] [-TargetMigration <String>] [-Script] [-Force] [-ProjectName <String>] [-StartUpProjectName <String>] 
    [-ConfigurationTypeName <String>] -ConnectionString <String> -ConnectionProviderName <String> [-AppDomainBaseDirectory <String>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: Is there some way to set the default startup project in source controlled files so that option wouldn't need to be specified?

Comment: @user433342 Not that I know of.

Answer (score 2):

i think i have the same problem too, vs2017 don't remember the default project that i sets as default.
he always sets someone else project as the default.

i find that the project that he sets as default is in the first  position by the solution file.

so i ended up by **moving the position of my favorite project as the first one on that file (.sln)**. so my favorite project remains the default.

i would be happy to have a normal solution to that odded situation.